# Crystal Reports Formula for Dynamic Field Names

Tags: dynamic, crystal-reports, report, formulas

I have tried figuring this out but to no avail. The database I am working in has fields that show the balance of GL Account based on period (e.g. `{GLAF.BAL1}`, `{GLAF.BAL2}`, `{GLAF.BAL3}` etc).
I am looking for a way to show the SUM of the balances based on the current date.

I have the following formula to determine what the current period is (our fiscal year starts 8/1:

```
if month(currentdate) >= 8 then Period := (Month(currentdate)-7) else Period := (Month(currentdate)+5)
```

Is there a way that I can create a formula that would basically do the following. Two examples to make sure it is clear:

Example 1 (current period = 4):

```
Balance =: ({GLAF.BAL1} + {GLAF.BAL2} + {GLAF.BAL3})
```

Example 2 (Current Period = 7):

```
Balance =: ({GLAF.BAL1} + {GLAF.BAL2} + {GLAF.BAL3} + {GLAF.BAL4} + {GLAF.BAL5} + {GLAF.BAL6})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the formula slightly like this:

```
if {?period} >= 1 then {GLAF.BAL1} +
if {?period} >= 2 then {GLAF.BAL2} + 
if {?period} >= 3 then {GLAF.BAL3} + 
if {?period} >= 4 then {GLAF.BAL4} + 
if {?period} >= 5 then {GLAF.BAL5} + 
if {?period} >= 6 then {GLAF.BAL6} + 
if {?period} >= 7 then {GLAF.BAL7} + 
if {?period} >= 8 then {GLAF.BAL8} + 
if {?period} >= 9 then {GLAF.BAL9} + 
if {?period} >= 10 then {GLAF.BAL10} + 
if {?period} >= 11 then {GLAF.BAL11} + 
if {?period} >= 12 then {GLAF.BAL12}
```

However be careful no values are `NULL` as this will need more careful handling.

Comment: Thanks!! This worked perfectly. I knew there had to be some obvious way I was missing, and this worked great.

Comment: UPDATE:
I had to adjust the formula slightly to account for the fact that accounting is always working one month behind for posting the numbers. so I just increased each interval by 1 and put "if {?period} >=1" at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of something completely "dynamic" but i'd just do something like:

```
local numberVar Balance := 0;

if {@period} > 1 then
  Balance := Balance + {GLAF.BAL1};

if {@period} > 2 then
  Balance := Balance + {GLAF.BAL2};

if {@period} > 3 then
  Balance := Balance + {GLAF.BAL3};

Balance;
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer produced the proper numbers as well. I went with the other answer simply because the formula is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Convert NULLs to zeros using *either* a SQL Expression or a Formula field.  You will need one for each database field (12 in your situation).

SQL Expression syntax:

```
-- {%GLAF.BAL01}
-- convert NULL to 0
NVL(GLAF.BAL1,0)
```

Formula field syntax:

```
// {@GLAF.BAL01}
// convert NULL to 0
If IsNull({GLAF.BAL1}) Then 0 Else {GLAF.BAL1}
```

Create a formula field to summarize these fields:

```
// {@Balance}
// place each field in an array; summarize array
// use formula fields to convert NULL to 0
Numbervar Array periods := [{@GLAF.BAL01},{@GLAF.BAL02},...,{@GLAF.BAL12}];

Local Numbervar balance:=0;
Local Numbervar i;

For i := 1 To {?period} Do (
    balance := balance + periods[i];
);

balance;
```